# How same columns comparison can result in difference between them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

This statement

```
SELECT * FROM TempTable t1
```

gives me this output:

```
id  idIndice    valor
----------------------------
13  11          11111111
13  12          11111
14  11          11111111
14  12          11111
16  12          11111
```

Now with a little change:

```
SELECT * FROM TempTable t1
WHERE (select count(*) from TempTable t2 where t1.id = t2.id AND t1.valor != t2.valor) = 1
```

I get this

```
id  idIndice    valor
----------------------------
13  11          11111111
13  12          11111
14  11          11111111
14  12          11111
```

t1 and t2 are references to the same `tempTable` and I can understand `t1.id = t2.id` but this:

```
t1.valor != t2.valor
```

is just too much for me. How come same columns as t1 and t2 are references for the same tables can be different?

And why this "= 1" at the end

Comment: As confusing as it is, a column with the name `ID` does not need to be a primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the second query essentially does is "*Select any rows for which the number of rows with the same ID and a different valor is 1*" i.e. "*Select any rows that have duplicate id's*"

That is why both rows with `id=13` are selected, as they are each others duplicate, and also why both rows for `id=14` are selected.

Note that if there are three rows with a same ID, none of them will be selected, because their number of duplicate id's wont be 1, but 2.

Comment: Thanks. I would vote up but I just can´t. Insufficient reputation. Sorry